# Alpha channel masking out other sprites on Cocos2d for iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, alpha, mask

The alpha channel of my sprites are (sometimes) masking other sprites out.

This is what it looks like: 
[image: screenshot]

As you can see, it doesn't happen all the time and all of the avatars here use the same texture file.
Has anyone had this problem before?

By the way, I used TexturePacker to export the sprites. Also I am using Cocos2d 2.0  and this is how I initialize it:

```
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds] pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 depthFormat:GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES preserveBackbuffer:NO sharegroup:nil multiSampling:NO numberOfSamples:0];
[director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];
[CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying a lot of different things, I found that what makes it work is simply setting the shader program on the node:

`node.shaderProgram = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionTextureColorAlphaTest];`

Comment: Can you explain your solution ? I need to mask a sprite(Master) using another sprite(Slave). I test this but cause run-time assertion. myMasterSprite->setShaderProgram( CCShaderCache::sharedShaderCache()->programForKey("kCCShader_PositionTextureColorAlphaTest"));

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your CCTexture2DPiexelFormat to a higher spec when you load this as a test:

```
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGB5A1];
```

See if that helps? As I remember, RGBA4444 is a much lower bit depth, but does offer improved performance of course.